How is the Control Spire preventing Ken's Black Digivice from Digivolving Wormmon but not Greymon?
How exactly was Ken's Black Digivice able to make Greymon Digivolve with all the Control Spires around and not Wormmon?
In Episode 9, Ken uses his Black Digivice to make Greymon Dark Digivolve into SkullGreymon even with all the Control Spires around.
But in Episode 39, Ken's Digivice couldn't make Wormmon Digivolve even with a Control Spire around.
So why is Ken's Digivice able to make Greymon Digivolve with a Control Spire around and not Wormmon?
